# jQueryUI tabs: stop rotating while hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

i build some rotatings tabs, using jqueryUI. While the user moves the mouse over the tabbed menu and tabbed content, the tabs should stop rotating. I read a [useful tutorial](http://urbanoalvarez.es/blog/2009/10/20/perfect-jquery-ui-rotating-tabs/), but it doesn't work for me.

The tabs still keep rotating though i move the cursor over them. Once i hovered the `div#menu-prime`, the tabs behave silly!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-prime").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } }).tabs('rotate', 3000);
    $('#menu-prime').hover(function(){
            $(this).tabs('rotate', 0, false);
        },function(){
            $(this).tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } }).tabs('rotate', 3000);
        }
    );
});
</script>

<div id="menu-prime">

    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li id="nav-fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected"><a href="#fragment-1">Kochen</a></li>
        <li id="nav-fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-nav-item"><a href="#fragment-2">Wohnen</a></li>
        <li id="nav-fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-nav-item"><a href="#fragment-3">Schlafen</a></li>
        <li id="nav-fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-nav-item"><a href="#fragment-4">Mehr</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">Content 1</div>
    <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">Content 2</div>
    <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">Content 3</div>
    <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">Content 4</div>

</div>
```

THANKS, 
Johannes

---

### EDIT: Enhancement

Thanks to Kim, the rotating tabs now wait when the user hovers one of the tabs.

```
$("#menu-prime").tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle', duration:100} }).tabs('rotate', 3000, true);
$('#menu-prime').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).tabs('rotate', 0, false);
});
$('#menu-prime').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle', duration:100} }).tabs('rotate', 3000);
});
```

Originally wanted the tabs to change on mouseover not on click. Therefore i modified Kim’s code:

```
$("#menu-prime").tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle', duration:100} }).tabs({event: 'mouseover'}).tabs('rotate', 3000, true);
$('#menu-prime').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).tabs('rotate', 0, false);
});
$('#menu-prime').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle', duration:100} }).tabs({event: 'mouseover'}).tabs('rotate', 3000);
});
```

**Now the tabs and especially the auto-rotating behave very strange once the user hovered any tab. I guess the two mouseover-events complicate each other?**

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
 $('#menu-prime').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).tabs('rotate', 0, false);
    });
 $('#menu-prime').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } }).tabs('rotate', 3000);
    });
```

**Edit:**
you are doing to different things on the same event. so you should proberly change your code to this:

```
 $('#menu-prime').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).tabs('rotate', 0, false);
    });
    $('#menu-prime').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle', duration:100} }).tabs({event: 'mouseover'}).tabs('rotate', 3000);
    });
```

and remove

```
$("#menu-prime").tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle', duration:100} }).tabs({event: 'mouseover'}).tabs('rotate', 3000, true);
```

Comment: Hi Kim, thanks you very much for this code. It works for me! 

But when trying to add a mousehover-event to the tabbed navigation, the two mouseover-events conflict each other: 

`$("#menu-prime").tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle', duration:100} }).tabs({event: 'mouseover'}).tabs('rotate', 3000, true);`

Comment: take a look here for refrence http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ and you should mark this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI since 1.9 has a lot of changes, now rotating tabs and pause on hover you can use only with extensions. For hover - just use my extension [jQuery UI Tabs: Pause on Hover](https://github.com/tigusigalpa/jQuery-UI-tabs-Rotate-Pause-on-hover)

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#imageCarousel').tabs({ fx: {opacity: 'toggle', duration:100} }).tabs('rotate', 3000);

     $("#imageCarousel ul li a").mouseover(function(){ 
               $("#imageCarousel").tabs('rotate', 0, false);

          $("#imageCarousel").tabs("option", "active", $(this).parent().index());

      });
       $('#imageCarousel').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).tabs('rotate', 3000, true);
    });
```